# How to Create table through json object using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, xml

[Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAXJT.png)
Hi in my code below I am trying to convert xml Data to Json Object. Using converted Json Object I am trying to create a table using angularjs. So here the problem is I am able to bind complete converted json object `{{employeeList}}` but failed to load individual attribute of json object i.e., `{{employee.EmpId}}`. Finally from my observation I found when the converted json object is directly assigned to

```
$scope.Employees = {
    "Employee": [{
         "EmpId": "4", 
         "Name": "Chris", 
         "Sex": "Male", 
         "Phone": [{ 
             "_Type": "Home", 
             "__text": "564-555-0122" 
         }, 
         { 
             "_Type": "Work", 
             "__text": "442-555-0154" 
         }], 
         "Address": { 
             "Street": "124 Kutbay", 
             "City": "Montara", 
             "State": "CA", 
             "Zip": "94037", 
             "Country": "USA" 
         } 
     }] 
};
```

the output is what I expected, but when I assign the direct result

i.e, `$scope.Employees=response;` it is not working. What might be the issue?

```js
 <script>
     var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
     app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
         $http.get("File1.xml", {
             transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                 var x2js = new X2JS();
                 var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                 return aftCnv;
             }
         })
         .success(function (response) {
             console.log(response);
             $scope.Employees = response;
             console.log($scope.Employees);
         });
     });
 <script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="httpApp">
    <div ng-controller="httpController">
        <div ng-repeat="employeeList in Employees">
            {{employeeList}}
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in Employees.Employee">
                    <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone._Type}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone.__text}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.Street}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.State}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone.Zip}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone._text}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.Country}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @Chinni check i have inserted image top of the page as Console log Image

Comment: Can you tell me what all are getting displayed and what all are not getting displayed in the table?

Comment: i am not getting individual details of an employee in to table such as<td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone._Type}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone.__text}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.Street}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.State}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone.Zip}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone._text}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.Country}}</td>

Comment: Check what does `{{employee}}` contain? Also, I see `employee.Phone` is an array and not an object. So you will have to use `employee.Phone[0].__Type` or use an `ng-repeat` on that.

Comment: @Chinni this is my json object http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2aa0e9f7517b2d3799b3b20c4c79992c

Comment: leave abot phone number what about employeeId,name.....etc

Comment: I still cannot figure out the issue. Can you open a plunker and add your code and share it? https://plnkr.co/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4atgSl9EPSV50qpxv4nI?p=preview please add xml2json to plunker

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue is, `response.data` after the conversion of the `xml` file has the following structure,

```
{
    "Employees": {  // note that the data you need is present in "Employees" field
        "Employee": [
            ...  // contains objects with employee details
        ]
    }
}
```

So, you need to populate `$scope.Employees` as follows,

```
// your required data is present in "Employees" field of response.data
$scope.Employees = response.data.Employees;
```

So, your `<script>` tag code will be,

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
    app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("File1.xml", {
            transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                return aftCnv;
            }
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            // your required data is present in "Employees" field of response.data
            $scope.Employees = response.data.Employees;
            console.log($scope.Employees);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mSTgh8QR7i5CSrSwq0SD) is the updated and working plunker.

Also, note that `employee.Phone` is an array and you need to use `ng-repeat` again to display the details as I've mentioned in one of the comments.